# ListView ArrayAdapter reverse of notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

notifyDataSetChanged updates the view/adapter when you change the object.
But how to have the object updated when the view is changed by the user (Checkbox checked)

I am trying to put the Checkbox onclick listener in the newView(...) and my adapter is in separate file.
My worry is that if I update the array object only internally then when the notifidatasetchanged is called the update will be lost. Is it true? Can I update the main object found in the Activity from the newView() found in the adapter in different file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `CheckBox` is checked/unchecked, the `onClick` method for that `CheckBox` will be called. When  that happens, you can change the object in the backing data for your adapter depending on whether the `CheckBox` is checked or not.

Please, go over the official tutorial: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/checkbox.html